# How do you apply per-directory PHP.INI settings with Zend Server?

Tags: php, configuration

I normally like to apply some application-specific PHP.INI settings in the root of each project, but in Zend Server the following methods do NOT appear to work...

- Using `.htaccess` with `php_flag` and `php_value` (Normally works with mod_php)
- `.user.ini` (Normally works with FCGI)

Can it be done without editing the server-wide PHP.INI?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've uncovered on the Windows version of Zend Server, **the `.user.ini` file must be in the actual folder of the executing script** – being in the document root is not adequate.  It's unfortunate and often inconvenient, but I haven't found another solution thus far.